# Rails deploy jasper report on jasper server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasper-reports, jasperserver, capistrano3

I am having ROR application with:

```
ruby '2.2.1'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
```

I am using [jasper report](http://jaspersoft.com), which I have created using jasper studio.

I have deployed reports on production-jasper-server from local(jasper studio), using jasper studio report publish tool.

And deploying rails application using Capistrano.

The problem is, whenever I change in my report on local, I need to publish changed report from jasper studio to production-jasper-server.

I want to automate this process using Capistrano OR something else which will deploy the changed reports on production-jasper-server along with production deployment.

I did few R&D in this and found [rest v2 api](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/creating-resource) of jasper server, but I didn't used this as I wanted to know best way before digging into this.

What is the best way to do this if you have better idea please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i think the best solution is to use the **Rest** or the **SOAP** web-services.

Use the [The v2/resources Servicee](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/v2resources-service), and check the [Modifying a Resource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/modifying-resource) section which mention the following :

> Use the PUT method above to overwrite an entire resource. Specify the path of the target resource in the URL and specify resource of the same type. Use overwrite=true to replace a resource of a different type.

check this [example](http://www.redrails.com.br/2013/03/07/ruby-client-para-rest-api-do-jasper-report-server/) on how to create a jasperserver rest api client in ruby.

and please check the following question [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/521804/ruby-rails-client-jasperserver) it has a small sample on how to create a client for the jasper server,but its built for the SOAP services.

Hope that Helps.